# DataTable column filtering with dom-select column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using Jquery Datatable for my table and for filtering data I am following this example

[DataTables > API > Multi-filter](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html)

This is working fine for regular columns. But I have some columns with drop downs as following.

[image: Sample]

For this column filtering is not working since it is considered the all entries of the drop down for filtering.

Can someone please suggest a way to put a filter for this king of column.
I am using DataTables version 1.10.7.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you applying DataTables to en existing table with dropdowns? Or are you using a plugin?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I am applying datatable for exising table. I am creating the html table first and apply "var table = $('#example').DataTable();"

Comment: I believe this may be a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040724/jquery-bootstrap-datatables-filter-column-containing-select-and-input-elements), but it does not have a solid solution, just a suggestion for a custom search. I would rather [RENDER the dropdowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031483/datatable-with-dropdown-column) so that the value is singular instead of all the values concatenated in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was fun:

```
const table = $('#example').DataTable({
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().eq(0).each( function (index) {
            const column = this.column(index);
            const title = $(column.header()).text();
            if(index === 2){
                var select = $(`
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Please choose</option>
                    </select>
                `)
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                });
                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                });
            }else{
                var input = $(`
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search ${title}" />
                `)
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'keyup change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
                    column
                        .search( val )
                        .draw();
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/n5ydvww0/).

After correction by [Mr. Polywhirl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1762224/mr-polywhirl) (Thank you!) I revisited the problem and adapted a previous answer:

```
(function() {
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.type.search.selected = (data) => !$(data).is("select") 
        ? '' 
        : $(data).val();
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-select'] = function(settings, col) {
        return this.api().column(col, {
            order: 'index'
        }).nodes().map(td => $('select', td).val());
    }
})();
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
        "orderDataType": "dom-select",
        "type": "selected",
        "targets": 2
    }]
});
$("#example select").on("change", function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        val = $this.val(),
        cellPosition = table.cell($this.parents("td")).index(),
        rowDate = table.row(cellPosition.row).data();
    $this.find("option").each((k, v) => ($(v).val() === val) 
        ? $(v).attr("selected", "selected") 
        : $(v).removeAttr("selected"));
    rowDate[cellPosition.column] = $this.prop("outerHTML");
    table.row(cellPosition.row).data(rowDate);
    table.cell(cellPosition).invalidate().draw();
});
```

Another working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/oL2uum3L/).

Hope that helps!

Comment: I converted your example into a [jQuery / DataTables plugin](https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/8n5zLo28/). I am not sure if it conforms to their standards though.

Comment: I am not sure OP wants filters at the bottom to be dropdowns. I think the issue is that the table contains cells with dropdowns and the filtering and searching needs to be on the cell dropdown value.

Comment: You're quite correct @Mr.Polywhirl, serves me right for not reading the question properly! When I get 5 minutes free I'll have a crack at the real question ;-)

Comment: Thanks @annoyingmouse and Mr.Polywhirl. I have fixed he issue using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040724/jquery-bootstrap-datatables-filter-column-containing-select-and-input-elements I will add my answer as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040724/jquery-bootstrap-datatables-filter-column-containing-select-and-input-elements).

To write our own filtering function, we have to extend the `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search` function of Datatable.The function has 5 parameters and you need the fourth parameter (the original data source for the row). This fourth parameter is a JavaScript array, where the original HTML code of the given columns of the given rows can be found.

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex,original,counter ) {
        var filterValue = $('#filterField').val();

      var valueToFilter6 = original[6]; // this is the column with select box
      if( valueToFilter6.indexOf('value="' + filterValue) != -1){
            return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
);
```

A complete working example fiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yaythgt3/3/).